# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError reading from nested JSONArrays

Tags: java, arrays, json, performance, heap-memory

I am importing data from an API which returns it in the format of JSONArrays inside JSONArrays, with 6 levels of depth.
In order to retrieve the data from the lowest level possible, I am currently looping from array to array to create a JSON object in the end. Something in the likes of:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject resultSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("result_set");
if (resultSet.has("field1")) {
JSONArray field1ResultSet = resultSet.getJSONArray("field1");
for (int i = 0; i < field1ResultSet.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject field1Object = countriesResultSet.getJSONObject(i);
    String field1 = field1Object.getString("field1Object");
    JSONArray field2Array = field1Object.getJSONArray("field2");
    for (int t = 0; t < field2Array.length(); t++) {
        JSONObject field2Object = field2Array.getJSONObject(t);
        String field2 = field2Object.getString("name");
        JSONArray field3Array = field2Object.getJSONArray("field3");
        for (int z = 0; z < field3Array.length(); z++) {
            JSONObject field3Object = field3Array.getJSONObject(z);
            String field3 = field3Object.getString("name");
            String field3_2 = field3Object.getString("token");
            JSONArray field4Array = field3Object.getJSONArray("field4");
            for (int m = 0; m < field4Array.length(); m++) {
                JSONObject field4Object = field4Array.getJSONObject(m);
                String field4 = field4Object.getString("name");
                JSONArray field5Array = field4Object.getJSONArray("field5");
                for (int n = 0; n < field5Array.length(); n++) {
                JSONObject field5Object = field5Array.getJSONObject(n);
                String field5 = field5Object.getString("name");
                JSONArray field6Array = field5Object.getJSONArray("field6");
                for (int g = 0; g < field6Array.length(); g++) {
                    JSONObject field6Object = field6Array.getJSONObject(g);
                    String field6 = field6Object.getString("name");
                    JSONArray kpiValues = field6Object.getJSONArray("kpi_values");
                    JSONObject finalObject = new JSONObject();
                    finalObject.put("date", DATE);
                    finalObject.put("field1", field1);
                    finalObject.put("field2", field2);
                    finalObject.put("field3", field3);
                    finalObject.put("field3_2", field3_2);
                    finalObject.put("field4", field4);
                    finalObject.put("field5", field5);
                    finalObject.put("field6", field6);
```

I then store this JSONObject in a JSONArray to later be exported and this is pretty much the process.
The problem here is that the information being retrieved is so big that it is causing me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" mid-way through the process. 
The API unfortunately does not have any kind of logic to send the data by pages or anything like that so I am pretty limited.
Does anybody have any suggestion on how I should approach this?

Thank you for your time

Comment: show us an example of a single JSON object you are reading in so we can better understand your reason for 6 for loops...

Comment: The issue is caused by 'holding onto too much in memory at once'. Since the source JSON string is entirely in memory and parsed (this means there is no requirement for the *API providing the JSON data* to support streaming/paging to work!), the increasing memory usage and program termination is associated with output generation. Can the output be streamed (eg. written immediately)? The memory could be further reduced by using a "PULL" parser. If neither of these are options, can more memory be allocated to the process?

Answer (score 0):

An [`OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) means the JVM has run out of memory pre-allocated to it.

This is generally the case of a memory leak, which I am not sure is the case here.

How large is the data you are importing?

Use these JVM arguments to allocate some more memory.

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M ...
```

The `1024M` can be adjusted as needed. `-Xms` being initial heap size, `-Xmx` being the max.

If you are using Eclipse, you can add these to the launch configuration.